# MessageFormat doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, messageformat

I cannot find my mistake if there is.

**I give `2` and `1` as arguments to `MessageFormat` but it returns `1` and `1`.**

I cannot overcome this issue. Also I cannot find any known issue about it.

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

My code likes the below. Error occurs in `TextHelper` class.

`Intl` class:

```
public class Intl {

  private static final String FILENAME = "MessageBundle";
  public static ResourceBundle MessageBundle;

  static {
    try {
      MessageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(FILENAME); // Uses the default Locale of the phone
    } catch (NullPointerException | MissingResourceException e) {
      Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
      MessageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(FILENAME, defaultLocale); // Uses the default Locale if an exception occurred
    }
  }

}
```

`MessageBundle_en_US.properties` file:

```
########################################################################
# HOW TO GENERATE A singleNotifSummary
######################################################################## 
# String singlePen Intl.MessageBundle.getString("singlePen");
# MessageFormat form = new MessageFormat("singleNotifSummary");
# double[] limits = {1,2};
# String multiPens Intl.MessageBundle.getString("multipen");
# String[] part = {"{0,number}" + singlePen, "{0,number}" + multiPen};
# ChoiceFormat format = new ChoiceFormat(limits, part);
# form.setFormatByArgumentIndex(0, format);
# Object[] args = {1};
# String result = form.format(args);
# Ex 1: Total 1 pen   // when args = {1}
# Ex 2: Total 12 pens // when args = {12}
########################################################################

singlePen=pen
singleBook=book
multiPen=pens
multiBook=books
# singleNotifSummary specifies only one type of materials
singleNotifSummary=Total {0}
# doubleNotifSummary specifies both of materials book and pen
# Ex 1: Total 27 books and 1 pen
doubleNotifSummary=Total {0} and {1}
```

`TextHelper` class

```
public class TextHelper {
    ...
    private int mTotalBooks = 0;
    private int mTotalPens = 0;
    ...
    ...


    /****** Variables that are used when generating Summary Text  ******/
    final double[] limits = {1,2}; // 1 means single and 2 means multi
    final String singleNotifSummary = Intl.MessageBundle.getString("singleNotifSummary"); // "New {0}"
    final String doubleNotifSummary = Intl.MessageBundle.getString("doubleNotifSummary"); // "New {0} and {1}"
    final MessageFormat singleForm = new MessageFormat(singleNotifSummary);
    final MessageFormat doubleForm = new MessageFormat(doubleNotifSummary);
    final String singleBook = Intl.MessageBundle.getString("singleBook"); // "Book"
    final String multiBook = Intl.MessageBundle.getString("multiBook");   // "Books"
    final String singlePen = Intl.MessageBundle.getString("singlePen"); // "Pen"
    final String multiPen = Intl.MessageBundle.getString("multiPen");   // "Pens"
    final String[] bookPart = {"{0,number,integer} " + singleBook, "{0,number,integer} " + multiBook};
    final String[] penPart = {"{0,number,integer} " + singlePen, "{0,number,integer} " + multiPen};
    final ChoiceFormat bookFormat = new ChoiceFormat(limits, bookPart);
    final ChoiceFormat penFormat = new ChoiceFormat(limits, penPart);

    /**********************************************************************/

    ...


    public String generateSummaryText () {
        String summaryText = "";

        if (mTotalBooks == 0 && mTotalPens > 0) {

            // In this case there is only Book(s) (single-type)
            singleForm.setFormatByArgumentIndex(0, penFormat); // applying the format to argument "{0}"
            Object[] args = { mTotalPens }; // total Pens count
            summaryText = singleForm.format(args);

        } else if (mTotalBooks > 0 && mTotalPens == 0) {

            // In this case there is only Pen(s) (single-type)
            singleForm.setFormatByArgumentIndex(0, offerFormat); // applying the format to argument "{0}"
            Object[] args = { mTotalBooks }; // total Books count
            summaryText = singleForm.format(args);

        } else {

            // In this case there are Book(s) and Pen(s) (double-type)
            doubleForm.setFormatByArgumentIndex(0, bookFormat); // applying the format to argument "{0}"
            doubleForm.setFormatByArgumentIndex(1, penFormat); // applying the format to argument "{1}"
            Log.v(TAG, TAG2 + " --> mTotalBooks: " + mTotalBooks); // writes 2
            Log.v(TAG, TAG2 + " --> mTotalPens: " + mTotalPens); // writes 1
            // Object[] args = { new Integer(mTotalPens), new Integer(mTotalPens) };
            Object[] args = { mTotalPens, mTotalPens };
            summaryText = doubleForm.format(args);
            Log.v(TAG, TAG2 + " --> summaryText: " + summaryText); // writes "Total 1 book and 1 pen"
            Log.v(TAG, TAG2 + " --> mTotalBooks: " + mTotalBooks); // writes 2
            Log.v(TAG, TAG2 + " --> mTotalPens: " + mTotalPens); // writes 1

        }

        return summaryText;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're referring to `0` in both `bookPart` and `penPart`. So when you pass `{1, 2}` to the formatter, it calculates the single/plural correctly according to the limits you've set, but prints only the 0-th arguments, which is `1`. You must refer to the pens argument as `{1}` throughout the entire formatting pattern.

The correct code will be:

```
final String[] bookPart = {"{0,number,integer} " + singleBook, "{0,number,integer} " + multiBook};
final String[] penPart = {"{1,number,integer} " + singlePen, "{1,number,integer} " + multiPen};
```

Look at the second example, line #2 at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html.

Comment: Yes! You are exactly right! It should be so! Thank you very much! I had overlooked it!

Comment: You save my hours and you made my day! Thanks again. After copy-paste I forgot to change it.